# Como alterar o formato de uma coluna direto no LOAD INFILE do MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Olá, eu tenho uma tabela 'x', com a coluna Valor, em DECIMAL, num banco de dados MySQL 9.

Ocorre que preciso importar dados em csv. Faço isso usando LOAD INFILE.

Nesses CSVs, o valor está em formato com vírgula, por exemplo, "1938,20".

Para importar nesse caso, eu importo como varchar e depois transformo com REPLACE(VALOR, ',', '.').

Queria saber se é possível já fazer a transformação na hora de importar os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer a alteração é bem simples

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'planilha.cvs'
INTO TABLE tabela_preco_produtos 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(codigo, produto, @var1)
set preco = REPLACE(@var1, ',', '.');
```

Determina qual o separador `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`;

Determina a ligação (Colocar multiplas colunas em uma) `ENCLOSED BY`, no exemplo se usar aspas duplas une os valores em uma coluna;

Determina o final das linhas `LINES TERMINATED BY`;

Informa-se o nome das colunas `(codigo, produto, @var1)`;

Efetuamos um `set` com `replace` para alterar o formato da entrada.